# What key is used for raw HTTP POST body?

Tags: java, http

I am testing an APIs that require raw POST body request parameter(the JSON request body in the raw format and with type `application/json`). I am testing the APIs in POSTMAN(classified areas blacked out):

[image]

As far my experience has been, there is always a *Key* that pairs a value(like *Key-Value* pair) in the POST body.(otherwise, how will you parse and fetch any attached data in the body ever?). Be it a *x-www-form-urlencoded request* or a *Multipart request*, you are required to defined some key to pair the corresponding value.

What's surprising is that the raw request body doesn't require any key specifically. Or, I am thinking that it has some internally generated well-known default key that every other server knows.

What is the underlying story here? What is the name of the default generated key if there is one indeed?

Comment: http has nothing to do with JSON. Another popular option is sending XML. And you have no key-Value pairs in XML. Just enter raw text and send it. I'm a bit confused by your question, because I do not understand what is NOT working?

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher : No, it is not about working. I have asked this from a learning perspective.

Comment: I put some effort and time to answer your question, so I appreciate any feedback in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57767722/1426227).

Answer (score 3):

> As far my experience has been, there is always a key that pairs a value (like key-value pair) in the `POST` body.

That applies to requests which the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In such requests, the payload is essentially a query string, where:

- The name/value pairs separated by the ampersand symbol (`&`).
- The names are separated from values by the equals symbol (`=`).

> What's surprising is that the raw request body doesn't require any key specifically.

That's correct. When sending an `application/json` payload to the server, the body of the request is the JSON document itself. There's no named parameters such as when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

> What is the name of the default generated key if there is one indeed?

There's no such thing as *default generated key*.

---

To better illustrate what I mentioned above, consider an endpoint that allows you to create tasks, supporting both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` content types. You would have the following:

```
POST /tasks HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

title=Send%20report%20to%20manager&completed=false
```

```
POST /tasks HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "title": "Send report to manager",
  "completed": false
}
```

The body of the request can carry any array of the bytes. The semantics (and how such content will be parsed), is driven by the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header:

> [**3.1.1.5.  Content-Type**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5)
>
> The `Content-Type` header field indicates the media type of the associated representation: either the representation enclosed in the message payload or the selected representation, as determined by the message semantics.  The indicated media type defines both the data format and how that data is intended to be processed by a recipient, within the scope of the received message semantics, after any content codings indicated by `Content-Encoding` are decoded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "key". Its just button in Postman UI that allows you to enter just that - raw body content - instead of eg validated json, or key-value map form. Its nothing HTTP related.

Answer (score 0):

The body has no key-value constraint, because in raw body you can insert evrythink.

Currently, the json format is used as standard; the API owner will provide you with a swagger to inform users what they accept as parameters and what comes back to you.

So the answer is: the key-value convention is defined by the API owner

Comment: *The body has no key-value constraint* Does the standard say that?

Comment: Yes. You can make your API and accept everything. Example: You can set into row all parameter tokenized by a pipe and manage them like a String.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course mapping happens between request body contents with the endpoint mappers. (But Request Body is not represented by key but payload have key value for mapping if having application/json type) : DeMarshalling

**I am testing an APIs that require raw POST body request parameter(the JSON request body in the raw format and with type application/json).**

Json of course is key value pair structure :-

example:-

```
{  
  "enCid":"",
  "projectTypeCode":"etst",
   "projectTypeDesc":"test"
}


public class ProjectTypeDTO {   ==> Mapper defined by endpoint

private String enCid;
private String projectTypeCode;

private String projectTypeDesc;
}
```

=> Here Mapping Working :-

```
 "someKey"= {    ==someKey is not need as body is assummed to be a mapping object 
                    ProjectTypeDTO and it is not persent in it.
  "enCid":"",   ==> enCid key mapped to field =>private String enCid;
  "projectTypeCode":"etst",
   "projectTypeDesc":"test"
}
```

Mapping is done on the basis of keys always if type application/json.

Answer (score 0):

For people that understand OkHttp, here is an example:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"user_id\":\"443485\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://www.example.com/examples/example")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```